# How can I make a code that counts the days from today and restart the counter when I press a button?

Tags: javascript

I am new at programming and I am trying to make some code. I want a counter that increases day by day and that should restart after I press a button. Can anyone help me? This is what I alreay did.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var then;
      now  = new Date;              
      function teste(){
        then = New Date;
      }



// 24 hours, 60 minutes, 60 seconds, 1000 milliseconds
Math.round((now - then) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); // round the amount of days
// result: 712


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="M" onclick="teste()"type="button" name="button">Restart</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have most of the concepts correct, but you have minor mistakes all over the place.

I would first make sure this code actually runs. Take note of the runtime error and fix them as needed (there will be some...).

The next thing you will need is `window.setTimeout`, [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-script-settimeout-setinterval-method/) is some direction. Based on what you have here (after fixing it) you should have enough knowledge to move forward.

Just a word of advice, it is always better to ask for help, or where to go next, than it is to ask for someone to give you a 100% complete example. Development has a lot of grinding and learning that has to occur and that never goes away.